# Fastest way for filling-in missing dates for data.table (cont.)

Tags: r, date, data.table

I am searching for an efficient and fast approach to fill missing data in a table with missing dates.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(read.csv(textConnection('"date","gr1","gr2","x"
                                            "2017-01-01","A","a",1
                                            "2017-02-01","A","b",2
                                            "2017-02-01","B","a",4
                                            "2017-04-01","B","a",5
                                            "2017-05-01","A","b",3')))
dt[,date := as.Date(date)]
```

Suppose that this table has all the information for `x` by `date` and groups `gr1` and `gr2`. I want to fill the missing dates and expand this table by repeating the last known values of `x` by `gr1` and `gr2`. My approach is as follows:

```
# define the period to expand
date_min <- as.Date('2017-01-01')
date_max <- as.Date('2017-06-01')
dates <- setDT(list(ddate = seq.Date(date_min, date_max,by = 'month')))

# cast the data
dt.c <- dcast(dt, date~gr1+gr2, value.var = "x")
# fill missing dates
dt.c <- dt.c[dates, roll=Inf]

# melt the data to return to original table format
dt.m <- melt(dt.c, id.vars = "date", value.name = "x")

# split column - the slowest part of my code
dt.m[,c("gr1","gr2") := tstrsplit(variable,'_')][,variable:=NULL]

# remove unnecessary NAs
dt.m <- dt.m[complete.cases(dt.m[,x])][,.(date,gr1,gr2,x)]
setkey(dt.m)
```

This is the output that I expect to see:

```
> dt.m
         date gr1 gr2 x
1: 2017-01-01   A   a 1
2: 2017-02-01   A   b 2
3: 2017-02-01   B   a 4
4: 2017-03-01   A   b 2
5: 2017-03-01   B   a 4
6: 2017-04-01   B   a 5
7: 2017-05-01   A   b 3
8: 2017-06-01   A   b 3
```

Now the problem is that `tstrsplit` is very slow on large data sets with a lot of groups.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121356/4121307) approach is very close to what I need but if I follow it I could not get the desired output as it fills not only the missing dates but the NAs as well. This is my modification of the example:

```
# the desired dates by group
date_min <- as.Date('2017-01-01')
date_max <- as.Date('2017-06-01')
indx <- dt[,.(date=seq(date_min,date_max,"months")),.(gr1,gr2)]

# key the tables and join them using a rolling join
setkey(dt,gr1,gr2,date)
setkey(indx,gr1,gr2,date)
dt0 <- dt[indx,roll=TRUE][,.(date,gr1,gr2,x)]
setkey(dt0,date)
```

And this is not the output that I expect to see:

```
> dt0
          date gr1 gr2  x
 1: 2017-01-01   A   a  1
 2: 2017-01-01   A   b NA
 3: 2017-01-01   B   a NA
 4: 2017-02-01   A   a  1
 5: 2017-02-01   A   b  2
 6: 2017-02-01   B   a  4
 7: 2017-03-01   A   a  1
 8: 2017-03-01   A   b  2
 9: 2017-03-01   B   a  4
10: 2017-04-01   A   a  1
11: 2017-04-01   A   b  2
12: 2017-04-01   B   a  5
13: 2017-05-01   A   a  1
14: 2017-05-01   A   b  3
15: 2017-05-01   B   a  5
16: 2017-06-01   A   a  1
17: 2017-06-01   A   b  3
18: 2017-06-01   B   a  5
```

What is the best (fastest) way to reproduce my output above (`dt.m`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On rolling join, one 'normal' join and some column switching, aaaand you're done :)

```
temp <- dates[, near.date := dt[dates, x.date, on = .(date=ddate), roll = TRUE, mult = "first"]][]
dt[temp, on = .(date = near.date)][, date := ddate][,ddate := NULL][]

#          date gr1 gr2 x
# 1: 2017-01-01   A   a 1
# 2: 2017-02-01   A   b 2
# 3: 2017-02-01   B   a 4
# 4: 2017-03-01   A   b 2
# 5: 2017-03-01   B   a 4
# 6: 2017-04-01   B   a 5
# 7: 2017-05-01   A   b 3
# 8: 2017-06-01   A   b 3
```

You can (of course) make it a one-liner by integrating the first row into the last.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be the fastest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use IDate and an integer counter for the sequence of dates:

```
dt[, date := as.IDate(date)]
dates = seq(as.IDate("2017-01-01"), as.IDate("2017-06-01"), by="month")
dDT = data.table(date = dates)[, dseq := .I][]

dt[dDT, on=.(date), dseq := i.dseq]
```

Then enumerate all desired combos (gr1, gr2, dseq) and do a couple update joins:

```
cDT = CJ(dseq = dDT$dseq, gr1 = unique(dt$gr1), gr2 = unique(dt$gr2))

cDT[, x := dt[cDT, on=.(gr1, gr2, dseq), x.x]]
cDT[is.na(x), x := dt[copy(.SD), on=.(gr1, gr2, dseq), roll=1L, x.x]]

res = cDT[!is.na(x)]
res[dDT, on=.(dseq), date := i.date]

    dseq gr1 gr2 x       date
 1:    1   A   a 1 2017-01-01
 2:    2   A   a 1 2017-02-01
 3:    2   A   b 2 2017-02-01
 4:    2   B   a 4 2017-02-01
 5:    3   A   b 2 2017-03-01
 6:    3   B   a 4 2017-03-01
 7:    4   B   a 5 2017-04-01
 8:    5   A   b 3 2017-05-01
 9:    5   B   a 5 2017-05-01
10:    6   A   b 3 2017-06-01
```

There are two extra rows here compared with what the OP expected

```
res[!dt.m, on=.(date, gr1, gr2)]

   dseq gr1 gr2 x       date
1:    2   A   a 1 2017-02-01
2:    5   B   a 5 2017-05-01
```

since I am treating each missing gr1 x gr2 value independently, rather than filling it iff the date is not in `dt` at all (as in the OP). To apply that rule...

```
drop_rows = res[!dt, on=.(gr1,gr2,date)][date %in% dt$date, .(gr1,gr2,date)]
res[!drop_rows, on=names(drop_rows)]
```

(The `copy(.SD)` is needed because of a [likely bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926).)

Comment: Thanks. As you mention your OP has extra rows and it does not solve my problem. Could you correct it so it does not include the extra rows? Please, benchmark it against @Wimpel solution.

Comment: @Svilen Okay, I've corrected it. I am pretty sure Wimpel's approach is more efficient, and the example is not scalable to a large size (usually, you'd want to make an example that scales as a function of `n` or something in the OP), so I don't have a benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

`dt` should have NA for all unique `date` for each combi of `gr*` but is not showing up. Hence, we use `CJ` and a join to fill those missing dates with NA for x.

After that, expand the dataset for all required `ddates`.

Finally, filter away rows where x is `NA` and order by date to make output have the same characteristics as the original `dt`.

```
dt[, g := .GRP, .(gr1, gr2)][
    CJ(date=date, g=g, unique=T), on=.(date, g)][, 
        .SD[.(date=ddate), on=.(date), roll=Inf], .(g)][
            !is.na(x)][order(date)]
```

output:

```
   g       date gr1 gr2 x
1: 1 2017-01-01   A   a 1
2: 2 2017-02-01   A   b 2
3: 3 2017-02-01   B   a 4
4: 2 2017-03-01   A   b 2
5: 3 2017-03-01   B   a 4
6: 3 2017-04-01   B   a 5
7: 2 2017-05-01   A   b 3
8: 2 2017-06-01   A   b 3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('date,gr1,gr2,x
    2017-01-01,A,a,1
    2017-02-01,A,b,2
    2017-02-01,B,a,4
    2017-04-01,B,a,5
    2017-05-01,A,b,3')
dt[,date := as.Date(date)] 

date_min <- as.Date('2017-01-01')
date_max <- as.Date('2017-06-01')
ddate = seq.Date(date_min, date_max,by = 'month')
```

Please try on your actual dataset.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is ok but it is much slower compared to @Wimpel approach on my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit similar to another question, although note precisely a duplicate.  The approach is similar, but with data.tables and with multiple columns.  See also: [Fill in missing date and fill with the data above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024011/fill-in-missing-date-and-fill-with-the-data-above/55025968#55025968)

Here, it's unclear if you're seeking to fill-in columns gr2 and x or what gr2 is doing.  I'm assuming you're seeking to fill-in gaps with dates in 1-month increments.   Also as input data's max month is 5 (May) the example desired output has up until 6 (June) so it's unclear how June is reached if the goal is to fill-in between input dates -- but if there's an external maximum, this can be set instead of the max of input dates

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
dt <- as.data.table(read.csv(textConnection('"date","gr1","gr2","x"
                                            "2017-01-01","A","a",1
                                            "2017-02-01","A","b",2
                                            "2017-02-01","B","a",4
                                            "2017-04-01","B","a",5
                                            "2017-05-01","A","b",3')))
dt[,date := as.Date(date)] 
setkeyv(dt,"date")

all_date_groups <- dt[,list(date=seq.Date(from=min(.SD$date),to=max(.SD$date),by="1 month")),by="gr1"]
setkeyv(all_date_groups,"date")

all_dates_dt <- dt[all_date_groups,on=c("date","gr1")]
setorderv(all_dates_dt,c("gr1","date"))

all_dates_dt <- fill(all_dates_dt,c("gr2","x"))
setorderv(all_dates_dt,c("date","gr1"))
all_dates_dt
```

Results:

```
> all_dates_dt
         date gr1 gr2 x
1: 2017-01-01   A   a 1
2: 2017-02-01   A   b 2
3: 2017-02-01   B   a 4
4: 2017-03-01   A   b 2
5: 2017-03-01   B   a 4
6: 2017-04-01   A   b 2
7: 2017-04-01   B   a 5
8: 2017-05-01   A   b 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry for not being clear in my question. Actually, I use `gr1` and `gr2` as properties of every `x`, so in the end I want to repeat the value of all `x` from previous day regardless of whether it is a gap between dates in the dataset of future days. Also, I don't want to fill the missing day with `x` which does not exist in the previous day. In your case the solution does not fill correctly future dates. If you decide to correct it, please, benchmark it against @Wimpel solution.